# Domain Masking - Youtube link will not work

Tags: html, web-hosting, domain-name

I mask my domain name as I use my university free web hosting because I'm a poor student.

I have a link in my portfolio site to a Youtube video but it will not let me click on the link... the only way to open it is to right click and open in new window/tab.

How can I avoid this..?

The site is www.Grice95.co.uk and the link is in he far left 'CAMERA USE' icon.

Thanks Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way around this is to get the iframe embed code and take the URL from there.
Taking this will redirect your youtube link to a full screen embed of your video that works whilst still retaining the masked url.

Thanks to 'thepio'

Answer (score 1):

You could try a hax like setting the href like this:

```
<a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/v/_djf6rZ_0i4">
  <img alt="" src="../images/large/cam-txtdriving.png">
  <p>Text Driving - The Unwanted Outcomes (Intermediate)</p>
</a>
```

Or:

```
<a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_djf6rZ_0i4&output=embed">
  <img alt="" src="../images/large/cam-txtdriving.png">
  <p>Text Driving - The Unwanted Outcomes (Intermediate)</p>
</a>
```

Or:

```
<a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_djf6rZ_0i4">
  <img alt="" src="../images/large/cam-txtdriving.png">
  <p>Text Driving - The Unwanted Outcomes (Intermediate)</p>
</a>
```

Comment: The last one 'embed' worked thank you very much!
Where did you get the different links from ?

Comment: Well the usual way of embedding the an iframe to a page uses the `/embed/` version and I have been doing all sorts of things with youtube embedding and sorts so these just popped up in my mind. That's why I gave you all three options in hope that one option will help you :P